# live tv streaming in android

Tags: android, streaming, television

hi i like to open live streaming tv in my android phone and i use this code

```
package com.Slama.streamingtv;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer(); 
    try {
        m.setDataSource("rtmp://ca-fss.tiscali.com/redirectsatchannel1/tvtunisi.stream");
          m.prepare(); 
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    m.start(); 
}

}
```

or i use this code

```
String LINK = "rtmp://ca-fss.tiscali.com/redirectsatchannel1/tvtunisi.stream";

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
```

but no video is displayed and nothing that happened then what should I do to fix my code? or where is the error please

Comment: Your `MediaPlayer` is not drawing to any surface. Consider instead using a `VideoView`, it might be easier. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: @KenWolf i use videoview but i have this erreur runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -i lo --jump RETURN res=768  ( i need specific permission to read live streaming video other to INTERNET permission ?)

Comment: That error is not related to VideoView use

Comment: @KenWolf i added my other code see if you find a mistake please

Comment: BTW I don't think `rtmp://` streams are supported by the native player. Please see the supported formats and network protocols here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html